# Completing a Startup Menu in Function - Python

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to finish writing this function that contains five different options and uses a While loop to allow the user to enter in their choice with the entry '5' exiting the loop. Below is the code I have so far, I'm having trouble completing the menu part within the def_main function. I keep getting an error after `else:
          break`

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

```
def main():

    menuOption = 0

    while 1 == 1:

        print("1. Expanded Sum\n2. Reverse Expanded Sum\n3. Reverse Integer\n4. Product Table\n5. Exit\n")

        menuOption = int(input("Enter correct menu option: "))

        while menuOption<1 or menuOption>5:

            print("Incorrect menu option!!")

menuOption = int(input("Enter correct menu option: "))

if menuOption == 5:

    return

    while 1 == 1:

        num = int(input("Enter positive Integer: "))

    if num <= 0:
        print("You have entered negative integer or zero.")

continue

else:
    break

if menuOption == 1:
    printSum(num, int(False))

elif menuOption == 2:
    printSum(num, int(True))

elif menuOption == 3:
    print(str(reverseInt(num)))

elif menuOption == 4:
    printProductTable(num)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()

def printSum(n, reverse):
    s = sum(range(n+1))
    if reverse:
        print('+'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)) + ' = ' + str(s))
    else:
        print('+'.join(str(i) for i in range(n, 0, -1)) + ' = ' + str(s))

def reverse_int(n):
    Reverse = 0

    while(n > 0):
        Reminder = n %10
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder
        n = n //10

    print(Reverse)

def printProductTable(n):

    for row in range(1,n+1):
        print(*("{:3}".format(row*col) for col in range(1, n+1)))
```

Comment: Seems like your code is not well formatted. Please re-formate it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting at the break?

It looks like your spacing might be off in the continue, I assume your else goes to the if at the top of the statement, but your continue does not match with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `while 1==1` you can write `while True`. And also you have already checked `while menuOption<1 or menuOption>5`. So if your `menuOption` is a negative number it already falls into this condition as, say, `-2 < 1`.

And also seems like your code is not formatted. Means, `continue` is just above the `else`. It will generate the error. Re-formate your code. Give proper indentation.